# How can I print the values of an array object buffer?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I print the values of an array object buffer in JavaScript?

I want to print the values of an array object buffer, where I get the values of object from the

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function() {
  var ab = fr.result;
```

Where `ab` is the array object buffer, it's a part of file API field.

Comment: Post the result **ab** value.

Comment: is that work for you ??

Comment: ab is a object array buffer ,it hold some values when a select a file using file api,ab includes file name + some values...